# Use a real component in a service test

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I am testing a service that has an autowired helper component. That component has autowired repo.

In my test, I want to use that component helper, not a mock. And I want to mock the repo for that.

But I can't manage to make it work.

The Service that I test:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl{
    @Autowired
    private Helper helper;
}
```

The Helper class that has autowired repo

```
@Component
public class Helper {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repo;
}
```

My test should be like this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    ServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    private Repository repoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private Helper helper;

}
```

I'd like better to refactor the whole thing but unfortunately, it's not possible...

Any help welcome.

Comment: Is `Repository` a class or an interface?

Comment: Repository is an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution, thanks for the help.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceImpl service

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private Helper helper;

    @Mock
    private Repository repoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private Helper helper;
}
```

That way, the mocked repo is injected in the spy helper, and the helper can be injected in the service.
The @Spy objects are actually instantiated, so if you don't stubb any of its methods, you'll get a "real" object.

Here, the mocked repo is injected in the helper and the helper injected in the service.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer constructor injection over field injection. (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40620318/2504962))

In this case you classes would look something like this:

```java
    @Component
    public class Helper {
        @Autowired
        public Helper(Repository repo) {
            this.repo = repo;
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class ServiceImpl{
        @Autowired
        public ServiceImpl(Helper helper) {
            this.helper = helper;
        }
    }
```

This way you can easily create a real `Helper` object with a mock `Repository` object:

```java
    ServiceImpl service;

    private Helper helper;

    @Mock
    private Repository repoMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        helper = new Helper(repoMock);
        service = new ServiceImpl(helper);
    }
```

Comment: I would prefer it too but unfortunately, I can't modify the class I'm testing

Answer (score 0):

If `Repository` is an interface (and not a concrete class) you can try the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();

    @Mock
    private Repository repoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private Helper helper;
}
```

Comment: Problem remains the same. The helper is null when used in the service because it's not properly injected (not a mock)

Comment: actually the solution was close to yours but it's the helper that should be annotaed with @Spy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load a configuration for your tests which gives priority to a mock repo **Tested**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {     

        @Bean
        public Helper helper() {
            return new Helper();
        }
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Repository repoMock() {
            Repo repo = Mockito.mock(Repository.class);
            Mockito.when(/* Mock your repo */);
            return repo;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private Helper helper;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        // Your test goes here
    }
}
```

Anyway, keep in mind that field autowiring [is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/). Switch to constructor dependency injection ASAP.

**See also:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39042441/1199132